# Why is rails trucating TEXT column to 65535 chars?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am saving a raw email in a TEXT column in MySQL with Ruby on Rails. It keeps getting truncated to 65535 characters, does anyone know what causes this?

MySQL is running with `max_allowed_packet=64M`

Using InnoDB for the storage engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It gets truncated to that length because... well, [that's what will fit in a TEXT column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html).

You need MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT if you want to store more than that.

Comment: Can you quote what you read on that page? I cant see where it gives this as the limit...

Comment: Under "Storage Requirements for String Types in MyISAM", there's a table stating that BLOB and TEXT require L + 2 bytes of storage space, where L "represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value", and, according to the table, is less than 2^16 (65,536). Consequently, you can't store more than that. MEDIUMTEXT will give you 16,777,215 bytes of storage, while LONGTEXT gives you just short of 4.3 billion bytes.

Comment: Note that even though it says MyISAM, the same applies to InnoDB, as the two storage engines don't have any difference as far as BLOB/TEXT storage limits are concerned.

Comment: I'm getting my string truncated to 27700 characters.  I'm guessing this is because I'm using UTF-8.  Even with LONGTEXT (I've checked the DB, that's the type), it still gets truncated.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Ponny: If LONGTEXT won't take your string, then it sounds like the issue is somewhere else. Ask a new question and give details; you'll have more luck that way.

Comment: Solved it.  Had a better look at my data - there was a bad character that I'm guessing was causing my string to be null terminated (or something).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails didn't truncate, MySQL did.

The TEXT type is limited to `2^16 - 1 = 65535` characters, [see the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Answer (score 1):

65535 is one of those "magic numbers" - it's 2^16 - 1. That's just what the maximum limit is for a TEXT column in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby expert, but the number 65535 caught my attention -- that's 16 bits (minus 1, which typically is special).  You're probably running up against a wall of the size limit of the type you're using.